# Passar dados de um form para outra classe

Tags: c#, winforms, vb.net

Eu tenho form1 bem bonitinho com botão bem maneiro e dentro dele tenho um botão toggle on-off.
Tenho outra classe.cs  e tenho uma condição nela, mais só vai executar caso aquele botao lá no form1 esteja ligado. segue no Form1.cs:

```
        private void metroToggle1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // caso ligado retorna true ou false algo do tipo
    }
```

Minha outra classe.cs

```
    if(form1.botao = true ou retorna 0 ou 1){

             // faz alguma coisa
     }
```

Espero que tenham entendi minha pergunta sou iniciante em c# parece simples pra quem tem experiencia mais pra mim ta osso =/. Agrade antecipadamente pela ajuda.

Comment: Cesar, está confusa sua pergunta. Como esta classe é usada? a classe não roda do nada, ou é outro form?

Comment: Você tá invertendo as dependências. A classe deveria ser usada no form, não o contrário.

Comment: Tipo em tenho só o form.cs puro só com a parte visual e os botoes ligar e desligar, e criei outra classe separada do form, onde de fato tem as acções ou o que será feito, mas só será feito caso lá no meu form o botão seja ligado, ou seja essa minha outra classe tem q saber quando meu bota do form foi ligado pra executar  alguma coisa. Pensei algo do tipo passar uma variavel que retorne se la no form o botao foi ligado e essa outra classe receber esse valor do botao.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cesar, se entendi, voce quer que quando voce alterar o seu checkbox e este esteja marcado ele execute uma ação.

Voce pode fazer assim:

```
private void metroToggle1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (metroToggle1.Checked)
    {
        Classe.Executar();
    }
}
```

Dentro da sua Classe voce vai ter um metodo chamado Executar

```
public static void Executar()
{
    /// faz alguma coisa
}
```

Comment: O método da classe não deveria ser estático?

Comment: È exatamente disso que eu tava falando, já consegui aqui ,isso me ajudou vlw Alexandre.

Comment: sim Willian, esqueci

Comment: Cesar, se a responsa foi aceita, voce pode marcar a resposta como aceita do lado esquerdo da resposta. http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers